# Name nodes of addplot from the third column

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, dateplot

I have the following code

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    height=9cm, width=10cm,
    title={title},
    date coordinates in=x,
    xticklabel=\month,
]
\addplot[blue] table[x=x1,y=y1] {
x1    y1   name
2009-01-01  40  name1
2010-01-01  50  name2
2011-01-01  70  name3
2012-06-01  70  name4
2013-06-01  100 name5
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

What I want is to label every point on the plot with labels from 'name' column. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please have a look at [my solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/418844/95441) given to a question of yesterday, which is basically the same as yours, but was tried to solve in a very complicated way by OP.

Comment: I do not agree with @StefanPinnow's comment, but you can (probably) achieve what you want by replacing `\addplot[blue]` by `\addplot[blue,visualization depends on={value \thisrow{name}\as\Name},nodes near coords={\Name}]`. And sorry, your question has been closed, this is all that I can do at this point.

Comment: @marmot, hopefully you agree that using `nodes near coords` is the key to achieve what OP wants. Thus, I could have chosen basically any answer where `nodes near coords` is used in a simple way (when data are provided as table). And there are plenty of them. Feel free to add more links to possible (duplicate) answers.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Well, I guess that we have a very different opinion on what it means when a question is regarded a duplicate. But yes, I agree that `nodes near coords` probably will allow the OP to achieve what (s)he wants.